# Single Google Map API key which I can use across all the Phones

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a android application which has Google Map. Currently I have generated MD5 fingerprint and basis on that I got Map API key which I have used in my code. And I can see the Map in emulator and as well in my Android phones as well.

But suppose if I am giving the same code to one of my friend. Then he also need to generate the MD5 fingerprint and then basis on that he will be getting a new Map API key and then he needs to replace my API Key from the XML file with the one he generated to make the Map thing work. Right?

Is there any way like I can get a single Map API key plugged in my XML file and whoever is running the project whether on emulator or phone he should be able to see the Google Map in the Phone without changing anything in the XML file?

My main objective is if I am giving my project to my friends they should be able to run my project on there Android Cell phones without making any changes in the XML file related to Google Map API key.

I was following this tutorial- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map API key is generated based on a keystore, with which you sign your .apk file. If your friends run your app using debug.keystore (for example they run it from eclipse), then they have to use the same debug.keystore that you use. Try to give them your debug.keystore, if you really need it. And of course if your friends need just to run your app, you can give them apk, signed with your keystore. It will work on all devices.

Comment: Yes my friends need to run my app that's all and Google Map should get shown on his device. So how can I give them `apk signed with my keystore`? That's what I am looking for basically. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Find apk file in the /bin directory of your project and give them.

Comment: Aaah. Make sense. And he can use the same .apk file to run it on the emulator and also on the phone? Right? And Google Map will be shown to him?

Comment: And do I need to do anything else before giving my apk file? Like- do I need to sign it (right click project -> Android tools -> export signed application package).? As currently If I go to bin folder of my project, I can still see the apk file there. So can I use that apk file directly?

Comment: Yes, he can use this apk on the phone and on the emulator. You don't need to do anything with the apk from /bin. But if you want to release your app on Google Play, you must sign it with another keystore. I usually use right click on project -> export -> export android application. Then you can create a new keystore or use one, you've already created. When you run your app in eclipse, it creates apk file and sign it with the debug.keystore, and put it in the /bin folder. Then it uses this apk to run on emulator or device. But you shouldn't use debug.keystore when you release your app.